# mongooplog is failing with unauthorized error

Tags: mongodb, replication

I am trying to replay the oplog from 1 replica set to another in mongo. I am getting an error, any idea why?

```
mongooplog --from "10.0.0.180:27017"  -h "my_rs/10.0.0.88:27017,10.0.0.88:27018,10.0.0.88:27019" -d my_db -u dbuser -p db_pass
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 starting new replica set monitor for replica set my_rs with seed of 10.0.0.88:27017,10.0.0.88:27018,10.0.0.88:27019                    
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 successfully connected to seed 10.0.0.88:27017 for replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 changing hosts to { 0: "10.0.0.88:27017", 1: "10.0.0.88:27018" } from my_rs/                                                           
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 trying to add new host 10.0.0.88:27017 to replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 successfully connected to new host 10.0.0.88:27017 in replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 trying to add new host 10.0.0.88:27018 to replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 successfully connected to new host 10.0.0.88:27018 in replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 successfully connected to seed 10.0.0.88:27019 for replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 Primary for replica set my_rs changed to 10.0.0.88:27017                                                                               
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 replica set monitor for replica set my_rs started, address is my_rs/10.0.0.88:27017,10.0.0.88:27018                                  
connected to: my_rs/10.0.0.88:27017,10.0.0.88:27018,10.0.0.88:27019                                                                                        
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting                                                                                                      
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] going to connect                                                                                                           
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] connected                                                                                                                  
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] starting from Jun 26 14:24:21:0                                                                                            
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [omongooplog --from "10.0.0.180:27017"  -h "my_rs/10.0.0.88:27017,10.0.0.88:27018,10.0.0.88:27019" -d my_db -u dbuser -p db_pass
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 starting new replica set monitor for replica set my_rs with seed of 10.0.0.88:27017,10.0.0.88:27018,10.0.0.88:27019                    
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 successfully connected to seed 10.0.0.88:27017 for replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 changing hosts to { 0: "10.0.0.88:27017", 1: "10.0.0.88:27018" } from my_rs/                                                           
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 trying to add new host 10.0.0.88:27017 to replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 successfully connected to new host 10.0.0.88:27017 in replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 trying to add new host 10.0.0.88:27018 to replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 successfully connected to new host 10.0.0.88:27018 in replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 successfully connected to seed 10.0.0.88:27019 for replica set my_rs
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 Primary for replica set my_rs changed to 10.0.0.88:27017                                                                               
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 replica set monitor for replica set my_rs started, address is my_rs/10.0.0.88:27017,10.0.0.88:27018                                  
connected to: my_rs/10.0.0.88:27017,10.0.0.88:27018,10.0.0.88:27019                                                                                        
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting                                                                                                      
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] going to connect                                                                                                           
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] connected                                                                                                                  
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] starting from Jun 26 14:24:21:0                                                                                            
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 } plogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }                                                                                                                                             
Fri Jun 27 14:24:21 [oplogreplay] { assertion: "unauthorized db:admin ns:admin lock type:1 client:10.0.0.88", assertionCode: 10057, errmsg: "db assertion failure", ok: 0.0 }
```

The `from` parameter is also an RS (with `noauth=true` set), but if i try use "my_rs/10.0.0.180:27017" it fails, doesn't look like the `from` parameter can use an RS address.

the username and password used for the replay on 88 is in the admin db as well as my_db.

**Update**

I have upgraded to 2.4.10. The upgrade seems to give more meaningful logging. On 180, I can connect to the local db (without auth) and do a `db.oplog.rs.count()` and get results (both on local and remote connections). However, when I run mongooplog with 180 as the from, I still get an error (this is from 88):

```
Tue Jul  1 10:16:29.034 [oplogreplay] error getting oplog
Tue Jul  1 10:16:29.034 [oplogreplay] { $err: "not authorized for query on local.oplog.rs", code: 16550 }
```

and i see a similar error in 180's error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongooplog seemed to buggy around authentication, and also doesn't seem to support filtering of dbs to replicate.

I have written a tool (gem) that allows replication between 2 replica sets. It's available at https://github.com/brettcave/mongo-oplogreplay

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the authentication database to the command line, as by default mongooplog is going to assume that your username and password credentials apply to the database your are applying the oplog to.

**--authenticationDatabase dbname**

> New in version 2.4.
>
> Specifies the database that holds the user’s credentials. If you do
>   not specify an authentication database, the mongooplog assumes that
>
> the database specified as the argument to the --db option holds the
>   user’s credentials.

so in your case I would add `--authenticationDatabase admin` to your command line.

Comment: so if i'm running 2.2, an upgrade would be required to get oplog to work?

Comment: Perhaps - you could try adding those credentials to the my_db database - the issue is it is trying to apply your login credentials to a different database. IF you have the same credentials in both admin and my_db it should work. Caution though I've not tried this on 2.2.

Comment: Hi John, see the update section on my original post - I've upgraded mongo and have tried setting authenticationDatabase to local, admin and my_db (the same user account exists in all 3 databases). Am still getting the error shown above.

Comment: From the latest error message it looks to me like your user does not have appropriate access to the local database and the oplog collection. I'd check out the user roles and give this user as much as possible (readWrite). http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/user-privileges/

Comment: will give that a try. might need clusterAdmin role.

Comment: i've given the user readWriteAnyDatabase & clusterAdmin in both admin and local databases and still getting the authentication error. I would think that the above permissions should be sufficient? Suggestions welcome...

Comment: Check this ticket - a similar issue for reading oplog with the same error message, was not fixed till 2.5.1. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9191